# Persisting with Doctrine2 to database with REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table where I store relations between two other table with a float indicating relevance between the two rows. I have unique key on the two reference columns. The problem is, that I have to rebuild it regularly, which is kinda lengthy. So, I can't just truncate the table while I'm doing so, but I can't insert the relevance for the same row while they would be duplicates either. That's why I thought it would be great to save the current timestamp to a variable, persist the relations with REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO and then remove everything created before the saved timestamp. However, I couldn't find out how. Any idea? I'm using Doctrine 2.2.0-DEV and Symfony 2.1.0-DEV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine 2 doesn't support `INSERT REPLACE` or `UPSERT`, sorry.

Comment: Still doesn't support?

Comment: @klipach nope, no further work was done on this front.

Comment: Then what is the best way to check before `flush` if entity exists? `find` and `findOneBy` seems to cache entities and return wrong results. Only raw SQL query returns correct results.

Comment: If you wrap things in a transaction, then you should be reasonably safe with `find` (depends on transaction isolation level, since you might be doing shadow reads).