# Symfony2 Doctrine2, is there a 'REPLACE INTO' function?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I did some research that apparently Doctrine doesn't support the `REPLACE INTO` so I was wondering if there was an equivalent? Is there a way for Doctrine to just do an `INSERT INTO` if the primary key does not exist?

Something like:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->replace($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Or do I have to write it as a condition? If entity exists, update, else insert?

Comment: Yes , You will have to put condition if u want to process both action insert and create in same controller ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persisting with Doctrine2 to database with REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800605/persisting-with-doctrine2-to-database-with-replace-into-instead-of-insert-into)

Comment: @lxg Not a valid duplicate -- the proposed duplicate simply notes that `REPLACE INTO` is not available, and does not cover alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

if the primary key do not exist you can do FindOneBy

```
$entity = $entity->getRepository('Entiy\YOurEntiry')
->findOneBy(array('field1'=>$value,...));
```

and than

```
$entity->setField($field);
$entity->flush($entity);
```